# Angular 2 Typescript: TypeError: this.validator is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm building a form with ControlGroup and I'm loading a class object in it. However I'm running into the error mentioned in the title half of the time. Some forms do load and some don't.

I have a class file like so:

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    sign_in_count: number;
    created_at: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    birth_date: Date;
    news_letter: boolean;
    fb_id: string;
    gender: boolean;
    phone: string;
    picture: any;
}
```

In my UserDetailComponent I load the class in the control like this:

```
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    userDetailForm: ControlGroup;

    constructor(
        private form: FormBuilder,
        private _userService: UserService,
        private _router: Router,
        private params: RouteSegment
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this._userService.getUser();
        if (this.user === undefined) {
            this._userService.getSingleUser(this.params.getParam('id'))
                .subscribe(data => (this.user = data, this.setForm()));
        } else {
            this.setForm();
        }
    }

    setForm() {
        this.userDetailForm = this.form.group(this.user);
    }
}
```

On that last line I get the error of which the stacktrace is below:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 TypeError: this.validator is not a function
    at Control.AbstractControl._runValidator (model.ts:146)
    at Control.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (model.ts:128)
    at new Control (model.ts:282)
    at FormBuilder.control (form_builder.ts:32)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (form_builder.ts:66)
    at eval (form_builder.ts:50)
    at Function.StringMapWrapper.forEach (collection.ts:132)
    at FormBuilder._reduceControls (form_builder.ts:49)
    at FormBuilder.group (form_builder.ts:19)
    at UserDetailComponent.setForm (user-detail.component.ts:95)
```

Comment: You might need to create the form in the constructor already and only update the value (or add/remove elements) when the data from the `UserService` arrives.

Comment: What is FormBuilder? Is it an import?

Comment: @StianStandahl yes it is an import of @angular/common - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/FormBuilder-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, will try that. Thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! This works, only thing is that the dirty property of the userDetailForm always gives the value false, even when you changed some of the information..

Comment: I guess this is not supposed to collect the information from the children. It does have this property because it extends `AbstractControl` - not sure though.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I had this error when I was binding an array of values in form builder the wrong way.

**What I did:**

```
fb.group({items: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

**How it should be:**

```
fb.group({items: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]})
```

You have to wrap everything into an array, otherwise angular thinks that `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is a *form control definition* rather than a *form control value*.

Comment: This! Works a treat, and it let's Angular manage the models itself without me having to write more code (with attending risk of this extra code getting stale/needing testing). Better way to solve it IMO.

Comment: Ah! Of course, if it's an array it's expecting the second value to be a validator. Would have taken me ages to track this down.

Comment: If you use an object to populate the formGroup and the entity has an Array-Property, you can wrap the arrays like this `// @ts-ignore` followed by `entity.property= [entity.property];`. And then `fb.group(entity)`.

Comment: How can I upvote this answer again as it has helped me twice

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me when I copied/pasted from a component that implemented Validator, but failed to remove the NG_VALIDATORS provider on the new component.

Comment: This just saved me a lot of time, thank you! It is tricky as there is no interface implementation and hence no error saying the validate method is not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Create the form in the constructor. When Angular doesn't find the form on it's first attempt to resolve bindings then it doesn't work.

`this.userDetailForm` just needs to be initialized with an empty group or with a few static controls. Then when the data arrives from the server, update the group by adding/removing controls and updating values.

Answer (score 3):

for me the problem was that i wrote formControl instead of formControlName

before:

```
<input
type="number"
[formControl]="test"
>
```

after:

```
<input
type="number"
[formControlName]="test"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked in my use of array inside another array using NG VALUE ACCESSOR, but it can be confused. The error message is very bad to find a way out, it's like value.forEach is undefined or this.validator is not valid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was

```
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators(""); // no validators
```

updated to

```
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators([]); // no validators
// OR
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators(Validators.required);
// OR
this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);
```