# External script file could not be found by angular cli

Tags: angular

I have this problem and I don't know from where it comes

error :

> zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function at
>   HTMLDocument. (script.js:6) at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
>   at process (jquery.js:3602) at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423) at
>   Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   (zone.js:195) at
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:498) at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487) at timer (zone.js:2281)

this is the angular.json file

```
 "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"  , 
          "./node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" , 
          "C:/ms-front-web/src/assets/js/script.js"
],
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you seen this, Asma?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564574/angular-2-typescript-typeerror-this-validator-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Use this script path:

```
 "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"  , 
      "node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" , 
      "src/assets/js/script.js"
 ],
```