# nested array in formgroup giving error: this.validator is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to limit users to vote only once on a `forumpost`. I have been struggling with correctly using arrays to handle this functionality in angular for a while now.

Right now my code is failing when loading all my `forumposts`. The error occurs when building the `formgroups` and when there are more than 1 `userId` in my `upVoters: string[]` so I assume my arrays are wrong. any help, tip or pointing me into the right direction is much appreciated!

my idea:

> add `upVoters: string[]` to `Forumpost` class.
> push `userId` into `string[]` when voting
> compare if `userId` is already in the voters `string[]`
> true => remove userId from array
> false => add userId to array

it is working great until I start loading up the array with multiple `userIds`.
after investing many hrs of research on SO and other coding blogs and similiar I couldn't find an answer that was able to help me solve my problem so I decided to ask the community for help. I found a couple articles to nested `FormArrays` but none I could find were able to help me with my use case or maybe I do not understand how to implement correctly

[Angular 2 Typescript: TypeError: this.validator is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564574/angular-2-typescript-typeerror-this-validator-is-not-a-function)

I am defining my entity and my mapping functions in my **forum.service.ts** file so I can use them anywhere in my application

```typescript
    export class ForumPost {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      writerId: string;
      upVoters: string[];
    
      constructor() {
        this.id = '';
        this.title = '';
        this.writerId = '';
        this.upVoters = [];
      }
    }

    mapFormToForumPost(form: FormGroup): ForumPost {
        const forumPost = form.getRawValue();
        return forumPost;
    }
    
    mapForumPostToForm(forumPost: ForumPost): FormGroup {
      const form = this.formBuilder.group(forumPost);
      this.handleVotesFromForumPostForForm(form, forumPost.upVoters);
      return form;
    }


    handleVotesFromObjectToForm(form: FormGroup, arrayUpVoters: string[]) {
      form.removeControl('upVoters');
      if (arrayUpVoters && arrayUpVoters.length === 0) {
        const upVotersForForm = [];
        form.addControl('upVoters', this.formBuilder.array(upVotersForForm))
      } else {
        const upVotersForForm = [];
        for (const item of arrayUpVoters) {
          upVotersForForm.push(item);
      }
      form.addControl('upVoters', this.formBuilder.array(upVotersForForm))
    }
```

in my application i have a page where i use an http.get call to getAll forumposts like this. the http request is called in the ngOnInit() of the forumList.component.ts file

```typescript
      forumPosts: FormGroup[] = [];
    
      constructor(private forumService: ForumService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private formHelper: FormHelper ) {}

      loadTopics() {
        this.forumService.getForumPosts(this.postsPerPage, this.currentPage)
          .subscribe(response => {
            for (const forumPost of response.forumPosts) {
              console.log(forumPost);
              this.forumPosts.push(this.formBuilder.group(forumPost));
              for (const post of this.forumPosts) {
                this.formHelper.disableControls(post);
              }
            }
            this.totalPosts = response.maxPosts;
          });
      }
```

my corresponding HTML looks like this forumList.component.html

```html
    <mat-card class="outerCard" *ngIf="this.forumPosts.length > 0">
      <forum-list-post
       *ngFor="let forumPostForm of forumPosts | sort: 'votes'"
       [forumPostForm]="forumPostForm"
      ></forum-list-post>
    </mat-card>
```

following my error stacktrace with corresponding locations in my code. you can see its failing when building a formgroup via formbuilder. i have added a console log of my forumPost just before getting mapped to a formGroup.

[image: stacktrace]
[image: code location]
[image]

Comment: I'd check line 42 and 47.

Comment: 42 is only where loadtopics function is called in ngOnInit. okay i will check and compare response data to my entities. updating deleting post all worked though up until adding more userIds into the upVoters: string[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone encountering same problem here is how i resolved my problem. i decided to refactor my forum.service file by changing the mapping functions a bit. instead of using the formbuilder to build a formgroup i defined the formgroup myself inside my mapping function like this.

```
  mapForumPostToForm(forumPost: ForumPost): FormGroup {
    const newform = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(forumPost.id),
      title: new FormControl(forumPost.title),
      writerId: new FormControl(forumPost.writerId),
      upVoters: this.formBuilder.array(forumPost.upVoters),
    });
    return newform;
  }
```

drawback of this is i need to add fields here when i add new variables to my forumPost entity. as it is located inside my forum.service.ts file i just need to make sure not to forget when adding new variables to my entities